# JQuery function access

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, split

Hello I'm using jquery splitter widget

[JQuery splitter widget](http://plugins.jquery.com/splitter/)

and I'm able to intialize it as documentation says

```
$('#foo').split({
    orientation: 'horizontal',
    limit: 10,
    position: '50%' // if there is no percentage it interpret it as pixels
});
```

What I don't know how to do (because my poort jquery knowledge) is how to destroy it i can see in js that there is a function **destroy** but I don't know how to access it.

[splitter javascript](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.splitter/blob/master/js/jquery.splitter-0.14.0.js)

I've tried something like

```
$('#foo').destroy();
```

or

```
$('#foo').split('destroy');
```

but this does not work.

Could you please help me with this?

Thank you very much for any kind of help.
best regards team ol

Comment: `$('#foo').split().destroy();` should work - are you getting any error

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to assign your instance to a variable and then access the destroy method through your reference.

```
var mySplitter = $('#foo').split({
  orientation: 'horizontal',
  limit: 10,
  position: '50%' // if there is no percentage it interpret it as pixels
});

// then you can do
mySplitter.destroy();
```